# Count multiple rows in dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe (classification of substances with the classes) in the following format:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Organic compounds | Benzenoids | Benzene | NA |
| Organic compounds | Benzenoids | Benzene | NA |
| Organic compounds | Organic oxygen compounds | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | NA | NA |
| Organic compounds | Benzenoids | NA | NA |

I need to add a new column with the count of the rows with the same value in all 4 columns (rows with same value in column 1-4):

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Organic compounds | Benzenoids | Benzene | NA | 2 |
| Organic compounds | Organic oxygen compounds | NA | NA | 1 |
| NA | NA | NA | NA | 1 |
| Organic compounds | Benzenoids | NA | NA | 1 |

My problem is, to add a new column in the dataframe, which count the amount of multiple rows (1-4) at the same time.

For 1 row I have used `table()`:

```
data.frame(table(df$"1")
```

But if I use more than one row, there is not the right output `data.frame(table(df$"1",df$"2",df$"3", df$"4"))`.

I also tried it with `count()`

I found no solution for this specific problem here. So I need your help, please. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
   count(`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`)
```